# "Unexpected indent" when trying to call os.system

Tags: python

Pretty simple question (probably) but I guess since im new to python im not super sure about how os.system works.

Basically I have a for loop (thanks to some help from SO) that goes through all my directories and runs a shell script (like 120 something different shell scripts).

```
import os

root = '/foo/'

for directory, subdirectories, files in os.walk(root):
  for file in files:
     if os.path.splitext(file)[-1].lower() == '.sh':
```

Basically what I want to do is this (if it were in unix) (ignore the IP address but there will be an IP address each time)
sh run.sh 157.111.22.134 >> logfile.txt 
THEN
sh remove.sh 157.111.22.134

I tried something like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

root = "~/users/me"
ip = '157.111.22.134'
for directory, subdirectories, files in os.walk(root):
  for file in files:
     if os.path.splitext(file)[-1].lower() == '.sh':
       os.system('sh ' + os.path.join(directory, file) + ' ' + ip + '>>' ' log.txt')
       os.system('sh ' + 'remove.sh ' + ip)
```

but it complained about the second os.system (saying "unexpected indent")

and im not even sure if I have it right? ideas?

Comment: The [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) is preferred over os.system().

Comment: It doesn't need to be super secure or complicated, it will only be ran by me alone.

Comment: Please avoid adding comments to your own question.  Please **update** your question to be complete and consistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing up your indentation (spaces vs. tabs). Use `python -tt` to verify.

Comment: it didnt complain about the first os.system tho :/

Comment: It's not complaining about either of them. It's complaining about the indentation.

Comment: Indeed your right, it was just pointing at the last one. I think my text editor was adding un-needed spaces. Thanks!